# How to save drawings in Livecode?

Tags: image, save, drawing, livecode

I'm a bit of a Livecode newbie so I apologize if this is obvious. But I created a stack. Added fields, buttons, code etc. Then I drew and painted some images. Saved. When I reopened the stack, all my image work was gone! aqrrg. Happened twice. Why?

Comment: Have you checked that the image object on which you drew the picture, is still available after re-opening the stack? Have you tried this with a stack with just an image object and no scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add an image object before drawing. Adjust it to the size you need, then draw on the image object and it will be saved with your stack. If you fail to add an image object first, your drawing will disappear, not sure if this is a bug or not, but it isn't logical because you do see the drawing.

Comment: Must be a bug! If I add a vector drawing the created graphic does get saved! I filed a bug: https://quality.livecode.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23235

Comment: In my experience when you start using a paint tool on a card without an image object already created, LiveCode creates an image object that covers the entire card. That is still the case, and you can open its property inspector and see the image object, even name it. But when you save and close the stack, the image is deleted. I see this in v. 9.6.1 and 9.6.2. Definitely a bug that's crept in fairly recently.

Comment: Agreed! Just checked in LC 8.1.8 and the bug still exists and the new painting does not show in the Project Browser, but in LC 5.5.5 it will save the new painting as an image when you save the stack.

Comment: Good information, @Paul. You ought to add it to hliljegren's bug report if you can.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem!